# get tree root of different DSL file in same project for xtend validation

Tags: xtext, xtend

I have 2 different DSL. These are linked in their grammar, in such a way that "hobbies" defined in 1 DSL, can be referenced in the 2nd DSL. I want to have  validation rule that all the Hobbies are referenced in the 2nd DSL.

How can I obtain all the defined hobbies of the first DSL in the validation file of the 2nd DSL?

The first DSL called "MyDsl.xtext" looks like:

```
    'I' 'am' name=ID
    greetings+=HelloGreeting* 'Hobbies' hobbies+=Hobbie+
    ('I_dont_like' detests+=[Hobbie|QualifiedName])?
;

Hobbie:
    'eg' name=ID
;

HelloGreeting:
    'Hello' person=[Person] '!'
;
```

The second DSL called "MyDsl1.xtext" looks like:

```
JustGreetings:
    greetings+=HiGreeting* stuff=Stuff
;

HiGreeting:
    'Hi' person=[imported::Person] '!'
;

Stuff:
    'I_also_like_to_do:' hobbies+=[imported::Hobbie|QualifiedName]+
;
```

The validation I am trying to do in the validation file looks like:

```
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Check;

import org.xtext.example.mydsl.myDsl.Person
import org.xtext.example.mydsl1.myDsl1.Stuff

class MyDsl1Validator extends AbstractMyDsl1Validator {

    public static val INVALID_NAME = 'invalidName'

        boolean found

    @Check
    def checkWalking(Stuff stuffs) {
        var myHobbies = stuffs.hobbies
        var definedHobbies = getPersons().hobbies
        for (i: 0..definedHobbies.size) {
            found = false
            for (j: 0..myHobbies.size) {
                if (definedHobbies.get(i).name == myHobbies.get(j).name) {
                    found = true
                }
            }
            if (found == false) {
                error("you are missing hobbie" + myHobbies.get(i).name + '.', null)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Current result: Right now I can import the Person type in the imports, that gives no error, but i do not know how to get all the instances.

Expected Result:
I can get a list of Persons defined in the other DSL, and use it to compare.

**Edit:**

Example inputs:

definition.mydsl

```
I am A
Hello B !
Hobbies eg walking
```

usage.mydsl1

```
Hi A!
I_also_like_to_do: A.walking
```

Comment: do you mean the root (container) of an eObject in the same file?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich I think it is the Root container of the other file, I'm in the validator of "mydsl1". I can import the root type of "mydsl", now i need the root (container) of that "mydsl" file

Comment: well but what i dont get. which file? all files? or the one of the person already selected? if yes why no just follow the person

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Well, only the person selected in my current file of mydsl1 would suffice, (that person is defined in mydsl).

Comment: but then i dont understand why you dont simply call getPerson() on the HiGreeting

Comment: Thanks @ChristianDietrich ! It did not occur to me that i can just do ```var allHobbies = jg.greeting.person.hobbies```, as i thought the person defined in the other file would not be part of the object tree in this file... My problem seems solved by just starting the check at a higher level in the tree and and then use the above statement, and compare that with ```jg.stuff.hobbies```